# How can I fix the TextInput issue? in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

If i write a text korean in ingreInput and use space twice, it will automatically create a dot

like this   안.

However, this happens only when i use Korean.

what should i do ? if i want to resolve this problem?

this is my code

(Upload.js)

```
    const IngreInput = styled.TextInput`
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid #A9A9A9;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #292929;
    text-align: center;
    `;

    const Upload = ({}) => {

      const [ingre1, onChangeIngre1, setIngre1] = useInput('');

    }
    return (
      <IngreInput
      placeholder="ingre1"
      value={ingre1}
    onChange={onChangeIngre1}
      />
    )
```

(useInput.js)

```
    export default (initValue = null) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);
      const handler = useCallback((e) => {
        setValue(e.nativeEvent.text);
      }, []);
      return [value, handler, setValue];
    };
```